# What happens when doing triple comparison? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

First up: I know this is not how one should do a comparison, this is merely a question of interest.
Let's say you do this comparison:

```
var x = 0;
if(1 < x < 3) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```

What is happening inside that if-statement so that the output is "true"?
Is there some implicite logical comparison happening. And how do I find out?

Comment: It compares the result of `1 < x` to `3`…

Comment: Note that you will get `true` for any value of `x`.  It's not really testing anything useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison takes place from left to right so `1 < x < 3` will evaluate as

`1 < x` first which is `false`, given that `x` is `0`. Here the next comparison will be,

`false < 3` which will be `true` because there will be implicit type conversion of `false` to numeric representation, which is `0`. So, the expression evaluates to `0 < 3` which is `true`.

Hence, when you do `true < 3` or `false < 3` then this boolean value will be implicitly converted to `0` as `false` and `1` as `true`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ECMAScript® 2018 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#Title), (7.2.14) this type of comparisson is performed as follows:

> **7.2.14 Abstract Equality Comparison**
>   If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>
> Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
>
> If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
>
> If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
>
> If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the
>   comparison x == ! ToNumber(y).
>
> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the
>   comparison ! ToNumber(x) == y.
>
> **If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison !**
>   **ToNumber(x) == y**.
>
> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == !
>   ToNumber(y).
>
> If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object,
>   return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
>
> If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol,
>   return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
>
> Return false.

And:

> 7.1.3 ToNumber ( argument ): If argument is true, return 1. **If argument is false, return +0**.

(bolds are mine)

So:

```
(1 < 0 ) < 3
 false   < 3
   0     < 3
    true
```